# How to draw the following Bohr's Atomic Model in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, chemistry, chemmacros, bohr

I'm a new user in LaTeX. I want to draw Bohr's Atomic Models like the following picture. Can someone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Here a suggestion:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\tikzset{
    atomH/.style = {draw,blue,circle,inner sep=0.25cm},
    atomC/.style = {draw,black,circle,inner sep=0.4cm},
    atomBr/.style = {draw,green,circle,inner sep=0.25cm},
    elecBr/.style = {circle, fill=white,draw=green, inner sep=1},
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}     
    
    \node[atomC] (C) at (0,0) {C};
    \node[atomH,above of= C] (H1)  {H};
    \node[atomH,right of= C] (H2)  {H};
    \node[atomH,below of= C] (H3)  {H};
    \node[atomBr,left of= C] (H3)  {Br};

    % electrons
    \node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=1,yshift=0.6cm,xshift=-0.15cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    \node[circle, text=blue,inner sep=0,yshift=0.6cm,xshift=0.15cm] (E) at (0,0) {\tiny \texttimes};
    
    \node[circle, text=blue, inner sep=0,yshift=-0.6cm,xshift=-0.15cm] (E) at (0,0) {\tiny \texttimes};
    \node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=1,yshift=-0.6cm,xshift=0.15cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    
    \node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=1,yshift=0.15cm,xshift=-0.6cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    \node[circle, draw=green, inner sep=1,yshift=-0.15cm,xshift=-0.6cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    
    \node[circle, fill=black, inner sep=1,yshift=0.15cm,xshift=0.6cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    \node[circle, text=blue, inner sep=0,yshift=-0.15cm,xshift=0.6cm] (E) at (0,0) {\tiny \texttimes};
    
    % electrons of Br
    \node[elecBr,yshift=0.57cm,xshift=-0.85cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    \node[elecBr,yshift=0.57cm,xshift=-1.15cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    
    \node[elecBr,yshift=-0.57cm,xshift=-0.85cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    \node[elecBr,yshift=-0.57cm,xshift=-1.15cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    
    \node[elecBr,yshift=0.15cm,xshift=-1.55cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    \node[elecBr,yshift=-0.15cm,xshift=-1.55cm] (E) at (0,0) {};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]